# Empty Advertising Dictionary in CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

While working with a TI peripheral I am experiencing the following.

1. Advertising data dictionary will occasionally not have any records
2. Peripheral name appears to change

Working with the hardware developer it appears that sometimes

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)prp advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

Is sometimes returning just the scan response data vs the advertising packet. Has anyone else experienced this and worked around it?

Rich

Comment: It discovers by "piece". So you may want something: `if(advertisementData && [prp name]){//doSomething}`. Your TI device advertise a name and a local name. iOS will replace it by the localName once it gets it.

Comment: Does that mean that i should allow duplicates to see all the information consistently?

Comment: I think so. I always allow duplicates keys, keep the peripheral in an array, update it if it was already in it, etc. iOS has a kind of "memory", so if you discover one, it will kind of remember a few things.